# JavaScript/jQuery - How do I improve this js code/ refactor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, refactoring

I want to know how can I improve this piece of js with respect to best practices/performance.

JS code:

```
var treeGroupTypes, treeType, leftLeafClass, rightLeafClass;
treeGroupTypes = ["tree-group-small", "tree-group-avg", "tree-group-large", "tree-group-large", "tree-group-avg", "tree-group-small", "tree-group-small", "tree-group-avg", "tree-group-large", "tree-group-large", "tree-group-avg", "tree-group-small"];
treeType = ["small-tree", "avg-tree", "large-tree"];
leftLeafClass = "left-leaf";
rightLeafClass = "right-leaf";

//Both the above arrays have css classes in them, and then the 2 variables as well. Basically the whole js codes builds some trees and appends leaves to them.

buildTrees(treeGroupTypes, treeType, leftLeafClass, rightLeafClass);

buildTrees: function (treeGroupTypes, treeType, leftLeafClass, rightLeafClass) {
        for (j = 0; j < treeGroupTypes.length; j++) {
            var treeGroup;
            treeGroup = $(document.createElement("div"));
            treeGroup.addClass(treeGroupTypes[j]).appendTo(".trees")

            for (i = 0; i < treeType.length; i++) {
                var leftLeaf, rightLeaf, leftIcon, rightIcon;
                leftLeaf = $(document.createElement("span"));
                rightLeaf = leftLeaf.clone();
                leftIcon = $(document.createElement("i"));
                rightIcon = leftIcon.clone();
                leftLeaf.addClass(leftLeafClass).append(leftIcon);
                rightLeaf.addClass(rightLeafClass).append(rightIcon);

                var tree = $(document.createElement("div"));
                tree.addClass(treeType[i]).appendTo(treeGroup);
                leftLeaf.appendTo(tree);

                if (treeGroupTypes[j] == "tree-group-large" && treeType[i] == "large-tree") {
                    for (l = 1; l < 4; l++) {
                        var more = rightLeaf.clone();
                        more.css("top", (tree.height() / 4) * l).appendTo(tree)
                    }
                }
                else if (treeGroupTypes[j] == "tree-group-avg" && treeType[i] == "large-tree") {
                    for (l = 1; l < 3; l++) {
                        var more = rightLeaf.clone();
                        more.css("top", ((tree.height() / 3) * l) + 10).appendTo(tree)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    rightLeaf.css("top", tree.height() / 3).appendTo(tree)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

CSS required:

There are 3 tree groups - avg, large, small , as per height, shown in fiddle. By group, it means it has 3 trees in this together and those 3 trees in each group are further sub divided as large-tree, avg-tree, small-tree

```
.trees { padding:0 10px;}
.tree-group-avg {margin:0 8px; display:inline-block;}
.tree-group-avg div {position:relative; display:inline-block; margin:0 10px 0 0; background:#83919F; width:2px; vertical-align:bottom;}
.tree-group-avg .large-tree { height:120px; }
.tree-group-avg .avg-tree { height:90px;}
.tree-group-avg .small-tree { height:60px;}

.tree-group-large {margin:0 8px;  display:inline-block;}
.tree-group-large div {position:relative; display:inline-block; margin:0 10px 0 0; background:#83919F; width:2px; vertical-align:bottom;}
.tree-group-large .large-tree { height:150px; }
.tree-group-large .avg-tree { height:120px;}
.tree-group-large .small-tree { height:90px;}

.tree-group-small {margin:0 8px;  display:inline-block;}
.tree-group-small div {position:relative; display:inline-block; margin:0 10px 0 0; background:#83919F; width:2px; vertical-align:bottom;}
.tree-group-small .large-tree { height:90px; }
.tree-group-small .avg-tree { height:60px;}
.tree-group-small .small-tree { height:30px;}
```

/*Below are the leaf classes which are attached to tree, left leaf class means it will be on left side of tree and right leaf on right side*/

```
.left-leaf i{width:10px; height:10px; border-radius:0 10px 0 10px; display:inline-block; background:#ACCF37; position:relative;behavior: url(css/PIE.htc); }
.left-leaf  {position:absolute; left:-10px;}
.right-leaf i{width:10px; height:10px; border-radius:10px 0 10px 0; display:inline-block; background:#ACCF37; position:relative; behavior: url(css/PIE.htc);}
.right-leaf  {position:absolute;}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="trees"></section>
```

jsfiddle link of what it produces: http://jsfiddle.net/5NrfQ/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @M42 , thanks a lot, I have posted it there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might stick to images instead of writing such complex HTML and CSS. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069535/is-it-better-to-use-images-or-css-to-keep-performance-of-a-webpage-or-applicatio) to decide if you need it.

If raster is fine, you could have 3 PNG's (since simple PNGs can be compressed really well): one for left leaf hanging on a trunk, one for right leaf (with trunk as well) and one for tree trunk without leaves. All of equal widths with transparent placeholders or styled with appropriate margins. Or you may use negative scaling instead of a second leaf. Probably won't impact performance too much.

So, to compose a tree, you could place several blocks backgounded with tree parts to form a column. Having a one-pixel high trunk image allows for easy vertical scaling. You could even base64-encode pics into CSS to avoid extra file requests.

While this requires a bit of preparation, this might be faster on older browsers, that can't handle complex CSS at nice speeds.

Comment: I think in that case, instead of using images itself, this can be done only through html/css only with no js, with the only downside that there would be quite a lot of DOM elements for this.

Comment: Both methods can work without JS. Your code just creates new DOM elements, so practically it's the same. And it can be done the same way, just with a bit different HTML structure. What I suggest is replace CSS border and round tricks with predrawn PNGs.

Comment: Hmm..that's right. And isn't it good to have border radius instead of using images of that, which will create extra http, just curious?

Comment: @whyAto8 base64-encode them into CSS and no extra HTTPs anymore. While this will make them bigger in size, they're incredibly small with adaptive palette anyway.

Comment: That's kind of new to me, but will try this anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update Code:

```
Line No              Code
 1                    $(document).ready(function(){ });
 11                   for (j = 0;l = treeGroupTypes.length ,j < l; j++)
 13                   treeGroup = $("<div />");
 16                   for (i = 0; l = treeType.length, i < l; i++)
 18                   leftLeaf = $("<span />");
 20                   leftIcon = $("<i />");
 25                   var tree = $("<div />");
```

Comment: Well, regarding the creation of elements using $("<div />") , I think $(document.createElement("div")) is the fastest. Please check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent/268520#268520  ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Have shorten a few lines of code

http://jsfiddle.net/5NrfQ/

```
for (i = 0; i < treeType.length; i++) {
                    var leftLeaf = $(document.createElement("span")),
                    rightLeaf = leftLeaf.clone(),
                    leftIcon = $(document.createElement("i")),
                    rightIcon = leftIcon.clone();
```

Comment: Well, not sure, but dont we need to declare other variables such as rightLeaf etc. The code might work though, but shouldnt we be declaring variables.

Comment: the variables have been declared...if you look closely its ',' and not ';' after each variable declaration.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I missed that. Just curious, is it kind of some best practice to do like this, or it gives some performance gain.

Comment: not a performance gain but you don't have too many var statements...just one var with all your variable declarations in one place.